# Resolving Ninject ILogger in Global.asax

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, global-asax

I'm trying to use the dependency resolver in the *global.asax* of an MVC4 project to get a reference to *Ninject.Extensions.Logging.ILogger*, but it's throwing a *NullReferenceException*. I'm using constructor injection elsewhere in the project to get instances of ILogger, and that works flawlessly.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        Response.Clear();

        var rd = new RouteData();
        rd.Values["controller"] = "Error";
        rd.Values["action"] = "NotFound";

        //this line throws a NullReferenceException with the stack track below
        var logger = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILogger>();

        IController c = new ErrorController(logger);
        c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
    }
}

at Ninject.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactoryBase.GetLogger(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.logging\src\Ninject.Extensions.Logging\LoggerFactoryBase.cs:line 61
at Ninject.Extensions.Logging.LoggerModuleBase.<Load>b__0(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.logging\src\Ninject.Extensions.Logging\LoggerModuleBase.cs:line 26
at Ninject.Activation.Providers.CallbackProvider`1.CreateInstance(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\CallbackProvider.cs:line 45
at Ninject.Activation.Provider`1.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Provider.cs:line 38
at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:line 157
at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 386
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs:line 56
at System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[TService](IDependencyResolver resolver)
at My.WebApp.MvcApplication.Application_EndRequest() in c:\Dev\Project\My.WebApp\Global.asax.cs:line 92
```

If I replace the DependencyResolver line with the following, it works, but is it ok to create multiple Kernel instances?

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = kernel.Get<ILoggerFactory>();
var logger = loggerFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Comment: You are missing some key info here; how is your bindings set up and where is the `DependencyResolver` for starters...

Comment: I'm using _Ninject.MVC3_ which I believe takes care of setting up the DependencyResolver (I don't do it manually anywhere).

I also don't specify a binding for ILogger. I'm using _Ninject.Extension.Logging.Log4net_, and that seems to bind it for me. As I said, ILogger works perfectly via constructor injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `Get<>` an `ILogger` because in that case it is not injected anywhere and the type can't be evaluated. You have two options:

1. Property inject the logger into global asax
2. Or better implement an IHttpModule and register for the Application.EndRequest event. Here you can do constructor injection

Comment: I opted to implement the required functionality in a HTTP module, with constructor injection for ILogger as you suggested. Thanks!